# How to include brackets in $set value of mongodb update query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So basically I am using update query of mongodb. Given query I tried:

```
db.trial.update(
    { userid: "a" },
    {$set : {'dates.yoyo':'{
                'ava':'np',
                'bcc':'yo'
            }' 
        }
    }  
)
```

The result I am getting is

```
"yoyo" : "{
'ava':'np','bcc':'yo'
}"
```

But my required result is:

```
"yoyo" : {
'ava':'np','bcc':'yo'
}
```

Basically I dont want the brackets to be included in the ""

Comment: Remove the quotes on `'{
                'ava':'np',
                'bcc':'yo'
            }' ` to set an actual object `{
                'ava':'np',
                'bcc':'yo'
            }` instead of a "stringified" object.

Comment: Thanks bro done write this answer so ill choose as solved answer

Comment: You can accept the one already there below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove quotes, so the update should look like:

```
db.trial.update(
    { userid: "a" },
    {$set : {'dates.yoyo':{
                'ava':'np',
                'bcc':'yo'
            } 
        }
    }  
)
```

to get this:

```
 db.trial.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56e165da3d541206f08c9cf6"),
        "userid" : "a",
        "dates" : {
                "yoyo" : {
                        "ava" : "np",
                        "bcc" : "yo"
                }
        }
}
```